# How to keep windows stationary while monitors turn back on

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have a current version of Windows 10, I have two monitors attached to the computer (one through Display Port and one through HDMI)

I keep the computer running 24/7 (never going to sleep), I have Windows set to turn off the displays after 10 minutes of no interaction.

When the monitors are off and I tap a key to wake up the monitors, the HDMI monitor turns back on first and the DP monitor turns back on ~3 seconds later (this lag is just the difference each monitor takes to power back up).

Due to this lag all the windows that were on the DP monitor when the monitor turned off are relocated to the HDMI monitor and then when the DP monitor turns on all the windows are relocated back to the DP monitor in a jumbled mess (the HDMI is vertical, the DP is horizontal)

Is there some setting in Windows that can help prevent this from happening? or is there a low-cost program that someone has written that can help me with this?

Comment: There are no settings I know of to prevent this. My clients just adjust the monitor content to suit them. Take the second monitor, use a screen saver for it and do not allow it to sleep. I think this will help you, but you may need to use screen saver and no sleep on both monitors

Comment: @Patrick There may be a solution here which may help you out, one for an explanation with  __VNarinyan__ "February 18, 2018  ...discovered on the Lenovo forums" and another right below that in the forum, from __RicoWang_732__ "...I had the same issue after installed a new video card connecting three displays, 4K + 2HD, using DP/HDMI/DVI..." https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-from-resizing-and/271709c8-b594-47db-9c6d-1f1bfb02aea0?page=2

Comment: Also See: VinceS2 a few after the 1st named on the same page :https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-from-resizing-and/271709c8-b594-47db-9c6d-1f1bfb02aea0?page=2  Hope it helps you out.